# What is appropriate configuration for mysqldump to use as backup

Tags: backup, mysql

There are some resources on how to dump databases using `mysqldump` ([1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-policy.html), [2](http://fosswire.com/post/2007/08/reference-making-backups-using-mysqldump/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875548/mysql-full-backup-with-mysqldump-exe) or [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427217/mysqldump-command-to-replicate-backup-created-by-mysql-administrator)) , but most of them are like "just mysqldump the whole thing". My mysqldump result differs from one I obtain from my hosting (different format).

Is there a "best" mix of parameters for mysqldump, that result in consistent results, is optimized for restoring later, etc.?

I.e.: should i use `--single-transaction`, `--add-drop-table`, `--add-locks`,`--create-options`,`--disable-keys`,`--extended-insert`, `--quick`?

We use mostly InnoDB, the backup takes place on galera rsync replicated node (so blocking should not be a problem). But I don't want to use XtraBackup, because we sometimes use the backups to reload database locally and test for bugs, etc. Ideally I want to have per-db backup files.

Comment: use as much default as possible, but verify backups. You may need one or another option, if you do you will know why. So,
mysqldump -A > dump.sql

Comment: I use `mysqldump $DB > /srv/backup/mysql/${DATE}/${DB}.sql` for now, but I thought that there is some good subset of switches to set. I mean - I don't need `single transaction`... until I do. I will validate the backup once (and every few months), but not every one of them. So it may be broken for months if some event will occur that is not in the DB now. There are no triggers now. Will they be dumped with default settings? That the kind of think I am after - things I might need but I don't right now...

Comment: If you admit that "it may be broken for months" and you can't tolerate that then the verification policy is bad, isn't it?

Comment: "My mysqldump result differs from one I obtain from my hosting" ... in what sense?

Comment: Michael - sqlbot: row-by-row inserts insead of bulk insert, but the fact itself is not important. I wanted to make sure, that the defaults are good enough for 99% of cases (would export triggers, would drop tables first, would disable keys, ... I can't think of all - probably because I don't even know I need them).

Comment: akuzminsky: 80/20. Imagine you are hosting provider. You don't know what your users will use. They may use federated tables, views, triggers, etc. You can't possibly anticipate all the cases that may emerge. But you may want to make sure you're exporting as much as you can as good as you can. So you think: probably someone is hosting provider and had to deal with this before me. So you ask on stackoverflow. Now you're me :) (except I don't do public hosting).

Comment: The defaults work OK. But I want to be sure that I can't possibly cover more area beforehand.